# Crystal Report error creating PDF

Tags: vba, pdf, crystal-reports

I try to create a PDF from Crystal Report with this VBA code:

```
Dim appl As New CRAXDRT.Application
Dim Rep As New CRAXDRT.Report

Set Rep = appl.OpenReport(pStrRapport)
Rep.ExportOptions.DiskFileName = pStrFichier
Rep.ExportOptions.DestinationType = crEDTDiskFile
Rep.ExportOptions.FormatType = crEFTPortableDocFormat
Rep.Export False
```

Crystal Reports seems to open but then I got the error and then nothing.

> Database Connector Error: ' [Database Vendor Code: 39 ]'

Do you guys have any idea what is the reason of the `error code 39`?

Comment: Sounds like some database connection error. Open the report definition file and see where it's trying to connect and whether that makes sense.

Comment: The code works great with any others Crystal Report files so it is this particular file. I tried to export the report manualy and it works fine. Every ODBC seems to be linked correctly.

Comment: *The code works great with any others* - hence I would look for something weird in the report definition, not in the VBA code.

Comment: It is just DB Connection problem not on creating a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

The Crystal Report does not seem to manage more than one datasource. I got a warning in Crystal Report but the export in PDF works well. It appears that VBA does not like that warning.
I will reorganize my datasource to have all my tables in one database.

Thanks!